# is it possible to disable mp3 controls when loading an mp3 file via http headers using php

Tags: php, http-headers, mp3

I'm creating a portfolio website for my music and want to allow users to play my songs without them being able to see the source/download the mp3 files.

I'm using PHP for this project and loading the files via HTTP headers.

```
<?php
 $mp3 ='72vox.mp3';
 if(file_exists($mp3)) {
   header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
   header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="mp3_file.mp3"');
   header('Content-length: '. filesize($mp3));
   header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
   readfile($mp3);
   exit;
  }
?>
```

When the page loads, my mp3 plays. However, I can't seem to figure out how to display any HTML on the page (and more importantly, how to place the audio controls in a div).

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm creating a portfolio website for my music and want to allow users to play my songs without them being able to see the source/download the mp3 files.

That's impossible.

In this case, the URL of your PHP script is effectively the URL of the audio file.

> When the page loads, my mp3 plays. However, I can't seem to figure out how to display any HTML on the page (and more importantly, how to place the audio controls in a div).

That has nothing to do with the way you serve the file.  You need to make a page with an `<audio>` tag, or with appropriate JavaScript.  When you go to this URL, it's not a "page" from your server, it's just the browser's default handling of your MP3 file.  Other browsers will just download it or open it up in the user's default audio player.

Comment: thanks for the update Brad - much appreciated. Can you provide a useful code example, or, point me in the direction of where I can find some more useful information on this subject?

Comment: `<audio src="path-to-your-audio-file.mp3" controls></audio>`

Answer (score 1):

> *"However, I can't seem to figure out how to display any HTML on the page (and more importantly, how to place the audio controls in a div)."*

*As an **example***...

Save your PHP code in a file called `getFile.php`.
Now create an HTML page with code like below, and use the PHP file as source in an `<audio tag>`.
 You can extend the HTML with your own "other stuff" code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="div_myAudio">
    <audio id="myAudio" controls>
    <source crossorigin="anonymous" src="getFile.php" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

<div id="div_myOtherStuff">

    My "Other Stuff" (HTML code) goes here or anywhere inside this document "body" tag...

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: Another way is to just `echo` the html tags from your PHP file. The browser will render the code. I'll add those details later, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - much appreciated.